# Viewing data in a custom object

Tags: custom-object

I have a custom object that I created in SalesForce.  I can't find anything that says, "read," or "view" data.  How can I view the data in my custom object?

Comment: In short: make a tab for it, make sure your profile has read access.

Comment: @Sdry Thanks.  If you post as an answer I will accept.  It should also be noted that this "tab screen" can be found by going to **SalesForce -> Setup -> App Setup -> Create -> Tabs**

Comment: Had no time for a full answser :)

Comment: @Sdry Sorry, he amatorVitae posted one sooner.  Thanks to both for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom tab for your Object via Setup --> Create --> Tabs --> New + follow prompt.

[image: Salesforce Setup page directing to "Tabs"]

Then click the tab, and click "Go" to see the "All" view.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you don't want to create a new tab just for a custom object, in that case you can do this:

1. Run the following in the developer console `system.debug(SObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.getKeyPrefix());`
2. Paste that at the end of your SF url e.g.: https://my-env.cs00.my.salesforce.com/a01

---

*Edit: Use `.getKeyPrefix()` per commentor below*

Comment: You can get it without doing an insert. `system.debug(SObjectType.MyObject__c.getKeyPrefix());`.

Comment: Or, if you already have an id of one of the custom objects: it's the first three letters.